# Apache Hive standalone

Tags: apache-spark, hive

How can I install and configure Apache Hive and integrate it with Spark without using Hadoop? I know Hive is build on top of Hadoop, but I need it as standalone version and to be worked with Apache Spark.

I tried to follow steps other presented on the web, but I failed to start Hive. I need a guidance in this manner.

Comment: please show which guides and which steps.  Also do you mean "hive" or the spark thrift sql interface.  If the latter - it can be as simple as .enableHiveSupport() on your local[*] session builder.  (use register global view to make data available).